# Como retornar o segundo menor valor em java?

Tags: java

Como retornar o segundo menor valor dada uma serie(de tamanho indefinido) de números em java? 
Tenho o código que retorna o menor valor, que ficou assim:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SegundoMenor {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(menor(input));
    }

    public static int menor(Scanner input) {
        int menor = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        while(input.hasNextInt()) {
            int x = input.nextInt();
            if (x < menor) {
                menor = x;
            }
        }
        return menor;
    }
}
```

Gostaria de pegar o segundo menor valor.

Comment: Não seria melhor voce fazer uma array e ordenar essa array e pegar o segundo item da lista que sera o segundo menor?

Comment: @TiagoFerezin depende. Se for um exercício para apessoa demonstrar que sabe fazer o algoritmo na mão, não. Se o exercício for para achar uma solução qualquer, aí pode ser.

Comment: @TiagoFerezin boa ideia muito obrigado!

Comment: /@AndradeLucas Poste a resposta de como fez pra ajudar outros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SegundoMenor {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(segundoMenor(input));
    }

    public static int segundoMenor(Scanner input) {
        int menor = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int segundoMenor = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        while (input.hasNextInt()) {
            int x = input.nextInt();
            if (x < menor) {
                segundoMenor = menor;
                menor = x;
            } else if (x < segundoMenor) {
                segundoMenor = x;
            }
        }
        return segundoMenor;
    }
}
```